# How to reinstall Windows 7 Home Premium OA without burning drives or usb?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I am a noob with ubuntu and linux and I just think it is better with windows.

My pc is a Compaq Presario CQ57 and It was pre-loaded with Windows 7 Home Premium OA.

I used all my hard drive space for ubuntu, and I would like to get windows back.

THe laptop never came with any recovery partitions or cd disks or anything, just computer, charger, and some Manuals.

Someone accedently threw away the box when i removed windows so I really never would know if there was a hidden cd or anything in there.

I have the product keys and everything just nothing to reinstall windows.

So could someone help me??????

Comment: Howto install windows is offtopic on this board.

Comment: I know, I am using ubuntu, does that help? o_o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can't reinstall windows without burning a CD or make a USB with windows,it's impossible at least that U don't have the windows installer CD.To reinstall windows U have to create a USB or a Cd with windows so U will be able to install windows.

Comment: lol ik i was making sure, im just stupid, I already broke my desktop then i forgot pass for my admin account on ubuntu, then the root pass i set is not working, so idk how to fix that, i'm not buying a new pc unless needed

Answer (score 0):

Ye I understand that ,but if u want to resolve the problem ask some friend of yours to make U an usb or CD with windows or to install it for U otherwise it's impossible to install it.